# Flash XML Data, Display Node Title on Click

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, movieclip

I am working on a Flash AS2 script that adds an instance of a movieclip for each node in an XML file. I have also included titles for each node in the XML file and I would like to display these when a user clicks on one of the individual movieclips. I have played around with clipevents and attachMovie but for the life of me I can't figure out how to approach this problem. Any ideas?

Ok Now with update script - yea!

```
var myXML:XML = new XML();
myXML.ignoreWhite=true;
myXML.load("map.xml");
myXML.onLoad = function(success) {
if (success) {
var myPin = myXML.firstChild.childNodes;
for (i=0; i<myPin.length; i++) {

var pinNumber = i+1;

_root.attachMovie("box", "pin"+i, _root.getNextHighestDepth());
var xpos = Number(myPin[i].attributes["xpos"]);
var ypos = Number(myPin[i].attributes["ypos"]);
_root["pin" + i]._x = xpos;
_root["pin" + i]._y = ypos;
_root["pin" + i].popup.titleBox.text = myPin[i].firstChild.nodeValue;

_root["pin" + i].popup._visible = false;// hide the title to begin with
_root["pin" + i].onRelease = function () { //when the pin is clicked...
_root["pin" + i].popup._visible=!_root["pin" + i].popup._visible; //toggle the titleBox's visibility
}

}
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO.

You could try something like this (when creating each pin):

```
_root["pin" + i].titleBox._visible = false;// hide the title to begin with

_root["pin" + i].onRelease = function () { //when the pin is clicked...
this.titleBox._visible=!this.titleBox._visible; //toggle the titleBox's visibility
}
```

(EDIT: changed the onRelease function to use 'this.titleBox')

The details would depend on exactly how you want it to behave.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Its been so long since I worked with Flash, I totally forgot about visibility. 

Im still having some issues though - it seems that the textbox is hiding itself successfully and I traced the onRelease function, so I know that it is working properly. However its not making the textbox appearing. Grrr...

Comment: I saw that too, apparently I turned the dynamic text into a movieclip ages ago. I have replaced the symbol with a standard dynamic textbox and changed the code to titleBox.text - still no good.

Comment: Does any of it work? are the pins being created correctly? try putting some trace statements in to check each step of the process.

Comment: Pins are creating correctly, text is invisible and the buttons are firing (tested it with trace()). The only thing that isn't happening is the dynamic text isn't becoming visible.

Comment: Perhaps the value of titleBox.text is note being set correctly from the xml? Maybe try using a dummy value (eg "mytext") instead of myPin[i].firstChild.nodeValue; to see if that's where the problem is?

Comment: The text is getting set correctly - when I remove the line that sets it ot invisible, it shows up just fine. I tried setting it to static text but it didn't change anything either.

Comment: Just to check, can you edit your question to include your updated code... in case there's a typo or something:)

Comment: Ok try changing the last line to: this.popup._visible=!this.popup._visible;

Comment: Brrrrrrrrrrravo! It works. Just for the record, do you know why it works?

Comment: Probably because by the time you click, the value of i has changed - you could test this by adding trace(i);